# G++ warning: built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked

Tags: c++, architecture, g++, x86-64, darwin

Whenever I try to compile my project (with the command line `g++ *.hpp *.cpp 2> log.txt`), that's what I get:

`log.txt`:

```
ld: warning: in configfile.hpp, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: in erase.hpp, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: in filehandler.hpp, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: in insert.hpp, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
ld: warning: in operation.hpp, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
```

Any ideas of why this is happening? I'm under OSX 10.6 (using latest Developer Tools)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're compiling header files (.hpp) which you shouldn't do yet.  Only compile source files (.cpp)

Rather than compiling all .cpp files, compile them one at a time and then link them appropriately.

```
g++ -c x.cpp
g++ -c y.cpp
g++ -c z.cpp

g++ -o tst x.o y.o z.o
```

Note that only one of your .cpp files can have a main() function - otherwise the OS won't know where the entry point is.

Comment: Compiling header files produces pre-compiled headers which is a part of the compilation process anyways. His errors are related to the linking phase.

Comment: @kisplit - I'd like to see him distill it down to what works, step by step, then he can pre-compile.  It doesn't seem he understands the process here and so I thought a little one step at a time might serve him well.

Answer (score 0):

I do not own a Mac so I'm kind of giving you the Linux version of what to do when this happens.

Look for a multilib version of gcc and recompile with the -m32 switch

```
g++ *.hpp *.cpp -m32
```

Try this. You CAN compile header files with gcc to produce pre-compiled headers.

Answer (score 0):

The g++ parameter `-arch i386` should do the trick for you:

```
g++ *.hpp *.cpp -m32 -arch i386
```

Is that correct?